# Assgin phone number to teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been trying to assign a number to a bot that I have created so that my bot can answer external calls or forward/transfer accordingly.

I have followed all the instructions from [Manage phone numbers for bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-phone-number#assign-a-phone-number-to-your-bot).

1. I have created a bot.
2. I have created an application instance (resource account), and used the command

   `New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance -UserPrincipalName abcaccount@xyz.onmicrosoft.com -ApplicationId XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX -DisplayName ABCaccount`

> This step works fine, I can see the resource account in Teams Admin Center. Here the `ApplicationId` is the `App ID` of my bot.

3. I have a free phone number ready to assign.

I am doing this from PowerShell as described in the documentation. But as soon as I try to assign the number I am getting the below error:

**Command:**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment -Identity abcaccount@xyz.onmicrosoft.com -PhoneNumber +1234567890 -PhoneNumberType CallingPlan
```

**Output:**

> Microsoft.Teams.ConfigAPI.Cmdlets.internal\Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment : The user 'XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX' is not found
>
> At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MicrosoftTeams\4.6.0\custom\Merged_custom_PsExt.ps1:1064 char:9
>
> Microsoft.Teams.ConfigAPI.Cmdlets.internal\Set-CsPhoneNumberA ...
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo   : InvalidOperation: ({ Identity = cs...iceEnabled =  }:f__AnonymousType100`5) [Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment_Set], Exception
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadRequest,Microsoft.Teams.ConfigAPI.Cmdlets.Generated.Cmdlets.SetCsPhoneNumberAssignment_Set
> ```

I cannot figure out why this error is occurring, I can see the resource account in Team Admin Center.
I also tried assigning a number from the team centre page but I got the same error.

Then I created a new resource account but this time I used the default ID of `Auto Attendant`  as mentioned in [New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/new-csonlineapplicationinstance?view=skype-ps&preserve-view=true). And I was able to assign a number successfully.

It seems that passing the `bot app ID` to `New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance` for parameter `ApplicationId` is somehow causing this issue.

If anyone could help me with some pointers that would be great. Am I doing the right thing here? If not, what's the exact way to assign a number to a bot so that the bot can answer external calls?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please reverify the userId ?Because according to the error response it seems that the userId doesn't exist.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT.  Thank you for the comment. Yes, I reconfirmed it and it's the right one. Also, when I try to assign a number to the same user from the `Teams Admin Center` page, I get the same error. I am suspecting if it is even possible to create a resource account using `Bot ID(Application ID)`. Because when I use the default IDs of `Auto Attendant` or `Call Queue` while creating a resource account, I can assign the number without any error. 
And if it is not possible to create a resource account using `AppID(BotID)`, then what is the right way to assign a number to a bot? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have assigned Microsoft Teams Phone Resource Account license ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-resource-accounts#assign-a-license

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, Yes. I did. I am able to assign numbers when I create a resource account as Auto Attendant or Call Queue. But when I follow the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-phone-number, it throws a user not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
with following steps it will work.

- create the application instance without application id
- assign the number
- assing the application id to the application instance

microsoft is working on a fix for this issue since some month

Comment: Hi Gerhard, thank you for the response. Actually, I did try the way you suggested before posting the question here but I couldn't complete the 3rd step. Could you please elaborate on `how to assign an application ID(Bot ID) to an existing application instance(Resource Account)`? Please do share if you have any reference documents. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please refer below document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-phone-number